# What is the actual reason for using boost:signals for few functions?

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-core, client, protocol

The `src/main.cpp` has `RegisterNodeSignals` and `UnregisterNodeSignals` to register the functions as boost signals as below:

```
void RegisterNodeSignals(CNodeSignals& nodeSignals)
{
    nodeSignals.GetHeight.connect(&GetHeight);
    nodeSignals.ProcessMessages.connect(&ProcessMessages);
    nodeSignals.SendMessages.connect(&SendMessages);
    nodeSignals.InitializeNode.connect(&InitializeNode);
    nodeSignals.FinalizeNode.connect(&FinalizeNode);
}
```

Let us pick `InitializeNode` as an example. The actual invocation happens in `src/net.cpp` which invokes the function defined in `src/main.cpp`:

```
GetNodeSignals().InitializeNode(GetId(), this);
```

I have the following question:

- Why cannot we simply call this function? Why should we complicate with `boost` library and signals?
- Has it got to do with performance of threads? If yes, then why only the 5 functions in `RegisterNodeSignals`

Answer (score 1):

Signals in OO is a powerful concept that allows binding instances together on runtime.

The signals concept allows to keep code modular and bind multiple instances on one signal emitter.

Just calling a function can work (for the `1-to-n` you would at least need another vector of instances, etc.), but would reduce the flexibility and modularity of the code.